# BeautifulSoup Scraping ERROR: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a countdown solver program to scrape solutions from a site.

How can I scrape the last line of this text?

[image: HTML CODE THING]

I tried this:

```
numbers = [23,43,65,43,7,3]
target = 200

r = requests.get("http://rve.org.uk/countdown?n="+str(numbers[0])+"&n="+str(numbers[1])+"&n="+str(numbers[2])+"&n="+str(numbers[3])+"&n="+str(numbers[4])+"&n="+str(numbers[5])+"&t="+str(target))

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print(soup.find('pre').text)
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: If you're getting an error, _show it to us_, don't just tell us "I got an error".

Comment: I'll take a wild guess that you have a parentheses in the wrong place.   `soup.find("pre").text` instead of `soup.find("pre".text)`.

Comment: Sorry. I get NoneType AttributeError.

Comment: As @JohnGordon mentioned, use `print(soup.find('pre').text)`

Comment: @Tiny.D Tried. it didn't work. :(

Comment: Don't just tell us "it didn't work".  _Show us the exact error_.

Comment: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

As I mentioned in the code @JohnGordon

Comment: Why are you using `r.content` instead of `r.text`?

Comment: Tried r.text too. It shows the same error. I think It won't work. Should I try any other scrapping method ? like robo browser?

Comment: BeautifulSoup can definitely do what you want; you're just making an error somewhere.  Have you tried saving `r.text` to a file, or printing it to the screen, then looking at it to make sure it is what you expect?

Comment: I've tried your example, `r.reason` returns `Forbidden`. So you cannot access the page because it's somehow restricted. The `status_code` is 403.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
          'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 'Cookie': 'v2=1495343816.182.19.234.142', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
           'Referer': 'http://rve.org.uk/countdown', 'Host': 'rve.org.uk'}
r = requests.get('http://rve.org.uk/countdown?n=65&n=43&n=43&n=23&n=7&n=3&t=200',headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
print(soup.find('pre').text)
```

It will work for you:

```
65 = 65
65 + 43 + 23 + 7 + 3 = 141
65 + 43 + 43 + 23 + 7 + 3 = 184
43 * (43 + 23 + 7 - 65 - 3) = 215
(43 + 23) * (7 - 3) - 65 = 199
65 + (23 - 7) * 3 + 43 + 43 = 199
23 * (7 - 43 / 43) + 65 - 3 = 200
(43 + 7) * (43 + 23 + 3 - 65) = 200
(43 + 7) * (23 * 3 - 65) = 200
23 * (7 - 3) + 65 + 43 = 200
(43 + 43) * 3 + 7 - 65 = 200
(65 + 23 - 7) * 3 - 43 = 200
(65 - 43) * 7 + 43 + 3 = 200
(65 * 3 - 23) * (43 + 7) / 43 = 200
(65 - 43) * (7 + 3) + 23 - 43 = 200
(65 + 43 + 7) * (43 - 3) / 23 = 200
(65 + 43 / 43 - 7) * 3 + 23 = 200
65 * (43 - 3) / (43 - 23 - 7) = 200
(43 - 23) * (7 + 3) = 200
```

Comment: sorry, this one will get the cookie from my local pc. not from the website

Comment: I will change the cookie @tiny

Answer (score 0):

Here's your example with the status code and reason printed. Also note that I've used a parser to specify that we are parsing HTML.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

numbers = [23,43,65,43,7,3]
target = 200

r = requests.get("http://rve.org.uk/countdown?n="+str(numbers[0])+"&n="+str(numbers[1])+"&n="+str(numbers[2])+"&n="+str(numbers[3])+"&n="+str(numbers[4])+"&n="+str(numbers[5])+"&t="+str(target))
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

print("The status code of the response: %d, the reason is: %s, the text returned is: %s " % 
     (r.status_code, r.reason, r.text))
```

The output:

```
The status code of the response: 403, the reason is: Forbidden, the text returned is:
```

Comment: Yeah, it's forbidden. Is there any other way to scrap content?

Comment: How did you get the sample HTML that you posted in your question?

Comment: I guess the correct URL is:
`http://rve.org.uk/countdown?n=10&n=10&n=10&n=10&n=10&n=1&t=11` ?

Comment: @JohnGordon From rve.org.uk and now it works. It was just a request problem I guess. They prevent "INSECURE REQUESTS"