# FinViz - Stock scraping giving error --AMZN not found 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup

I am new to BeautifulSoup package. 
I am playing with a code that I got from some website and I got stuck with the above error. Please help.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

def get_fundamental_data(df):
    for symbol in df.index:
        try:      
            url = ("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" + symbol.lower())
            soup = bs(requests.get(url).content) 
            for m in df.columns:                
                df.loc[symbol,m] = fundamental_metric(soup,m)                
        except Exception as e:
            print (symbol, 'not found')
            print(e)
    return df


def fundamental_metric(soup, metric):
    return soup.find(text=metric).find_next(class_='snapshot-td2').text

# Define A List Of Stocks And The Fundamental Metrics

stock_list = ['AMZN', 'GOOG', 'PG', 'KO', 'IBM', 'DG', 'XOM',
              'KO', 'PEP', 'MT', 'NL', 'ALDW', 'DCM', 'GSB', 'LPL']
metric = ['P/B',
          'P/E',
          'Forward P/E'
          ]

df = pd.DataFrame(index=stock_list, columns=metric)
df = get_fundamental_data(df)
df.head()
```

Comment: where's the error ?

Comment: AMZN not found
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'.Gettting same error for every stock

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix my own code based on this thread.

[BeautifulSoup Scraping ERROR: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44093182/beautifulsoup-scraping-error-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute)

My code after fix:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
          'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 'Cookie': 'v2=1495343816.182.19.234.142', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
           'Referer': "http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="}

def get_fundamental_data(df):
    for symbol in df.index:
        try:      
            #url = ("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" + symbol.lower())
            r = requests.get("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="+ symbol.lower(),headers=headers)
            soup = bs(r.content,'html.parser') 
            for m in df.columns:                
                df.loc[symbol,m] = fundamental_metric(soup,m)                
        except Exception as e:
            print (symbol, 'not found')
            print(e)
    return df


def fundamental_metric(soup, metric):
    return soup.find(text=metric).find_next(class_='snapshot-td2').text

# Define A List Of Stocks And The Fundamental Metrics

stock_list = ['AMZN', 'GOOG','ABC']
metric = ['P/B',
          'P/E',
          'Forward P/E'
          ]

df = pd.DataFrame(index=stock_list, columns=metric)
df = get_fundamental_data(df)
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and when you `print(soup)` in the for loop, you get this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;}
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;}
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
<div class="content-container"><fieldset>
<h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
<h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
</fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code did work last month. This is ref website:https://blog.quantinsti.com/quantitative-value-investing-strategy-python/

Comment: I have FinViz website credentials. But how I port that in the code? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try adding user name and password here:
`requests.get(url,  auth=('USER_NAME', 'PASSWORD'))`

Comment: I try to declare my user and password before function. But no luck. Or can you give me more details about where I can add those credentials, please?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102833/how-to-scrape-a-website-which-requires-login-using-python-and-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

@murali

your code is very good, i have a question: if i could import symbols from an excel table, it would be better for me. With your functions and the following code i have no data. In test.xlsx i have only one column with Symbol:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import os
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
          'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 'Cookie': 'v2=1495343816.182.19.234.142', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
           'Referer': "http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="}

def get_fundamental_data(df):
    for symbol in df.index:
        try:      
            r = requests.get("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="+ symbol.lower(),headers=headers)
            soup = bs(r.content,'html.parser') 
            for m in df.columns:                
                df.loc[symbol,m] = fundamental_metric(soup,m)                
        except Exception as e:
            print (symbol, 'not found')
            print(e)
    return df


def fundamental_metric(soup, metric):
    return soup.find(text=metric).find_next(class_='snapshot-td2').text

# Define A List Of Stocks And The Fundamental Metrics

#stock_list = ['AMZN', 'GOOG','ABC']
filein = "test.xlsx"
stocklist = pd.read_excel(filein)
metric = ['Symbol','Company','Sector','Market Cap','Shs Float','Insider Own','Market Cap',
          'Shs Float''Insider Own','P/B','P/E','Forward P/E','PEG','Debt/Eq','EPS (ttm)','Dividend %',
          'ROE','ROI','EPS Q/Q','Price','Prev Close','SMA20','SMA50','SMA200','Perf Half Y','Perf Month',
          'Perf Quarter','Perf Week','Perf YTD','Perf Year']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=stocklist,columns=metric)
df = get_fundamental_data(df)
df.head()
```